# How to implement contacts/email address picker like in Apple's mail application?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

when sending a mail on the iPhone/iPad you start typing the name of the recipient and list of proposals shows up. Either pick one from those, or continue typing an email address. Adding a new address turns the first one entered into a blue button like thing.

I would like to use this to allow users to select a couple of email addresses. Does anybody know if it is a standard component?

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really know if it is a standar UI control but i guess you could figure out something with the help of this video, this one uses the UI Person picker to display the persons name

http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/Selecting-a-contact-from-the-Address-Book-with-MonoTouch.aspx

and with some modifications you could search on contact list and display a modal view with suggestions of the emails in the list

with this example you can get all the emails in the contact list

```
ABAddressBook ab = new ABAddressBook();

ABMutableMultiValue<string> emails = new ABMutableStringMultiValue();
                foreach (ABPerson person in ab) {
                    ABMultiValue<string> personemails = person.GetEmails();

                    foreach (ABMultiValueEntry<string> item in personemails) {
                        emails.Add(item.Value, item.Label);
                    }

                }
```

With this code you will get all the emails on the contact list in the variable "emails" now you just need to access the "emails" variable and look for the email the user is typing.

Hope this helps.
Alex

Comment: Meanwhile I figured that you have to do it all by yourself. Even the fancy "blue buttons" containin the picked name is all custom made. So I guess I'll go that way to. Maybe I'll put some code on my website when I'm done.

Comment: nice, if you manage to accomplish it i would be really interested on your article hope you make it :D Good Luck!!